# Reconfigure windows 10 to uefi

Tags: windows-10, bios, uefi

So here's my challenge:

I just bought a Samsung 960Pro (which is pretty sweet).  I would love to just drop it in my machine as the boot drive, restore from an image backup, and be good to go.

One hitch:

My machine is currently configured to boot with BIOS, and the boot drive is formatted MBR (so my backup images are BIOS/MBR).

I want my updated to machine to boot UEFI.  Is there any way to convert my MBR/BIOS install to UEFI, or am I going to need to reinstall Windows?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g1eXD30Fox4

Comment: "Is there any way to convert my MBR/BIOS install to UEFI, or am I going to need to reinstall Windows?" - Yes;  It is possible to convert, your MBR partitions to GPT, thus allowing you to switch to UEFI mode